# Побитовые операции и аналог функции hash_hmac в JavaScript

Tags: sha256, php, javascript

Пытаюсь реализовать функцию [`hash_hmac()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.hash-hmac.php) на JavaScript, нашел библиотеку: [crypto-js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/).

Не совпадают хеши при равных значениях:

```
<?php
$value = "Информация";
$salt = "Соль";
$algo = "SHA256";

echo hash_hmac($algo, $value, $salt)."\n<br>";
?>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/sha256.js"></script>

<script>
var hash = CryptoJS['<?= $algo ?>']('<?= $value ?>', '<?= $salt ?>');   
hash = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
document.write(hash);
</script>
```

> php: d50311b934f6f12719b3906cf7d782a5ce7219d06dc564d584f6b8d51fa402a7
>
> js:  22addb19d925f0151da8cde18f1571764936a7b6b66348ef2f1374ecb5842ee2

Со стороны видно, что алгоритмы работают правильно, но чем-то отличаются. Никто не знает решение?

---

Второй вопрос косвенно касается первого:

Побитовая операция ИЛИ:

```
<?php
$value = "Информация";
$salt = "Соль";
$algo = "SHA256";
$hash = hash_hmac($algo, $value, $salt);

echo($hash ^ $value)."\n<br>";
?>

<script>
document.write('<?= $hash ?>' ^ '<?= $value ?>');
</script>
```

Условно выводит:

> php: ґ­аЋаµІ‡вґ¶Љ¶Ѓг±бЃіј
>
> js: 0

Почему JavaScript выводит 0, что я не учел?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Начнем с того, что не тем алгоритмом получаете хэш. Вот правильная библиотека:

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha256.js"></script>
```

Вот пример применения:

```
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("Информация", "Соль");
document.write(hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex));
```

И получаем [совпадающие хэши](http://jsbin.com/uratab/1/edit) для PHP и Javascript.

Comment: Да, теперь хеши совпадают, спасибо!

Comment: А про побитовые операции - по-моему javascript не работает со строками, только с числами. В любом случае вот: http://learn.javascript.ru/bitwise-operators

Comment: @Zhukov Roman возможно у кого-нибудь есть готовое решение, которое и со строками работает.

Comment: @lampa, могущество гугла не знает пределов :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908584/implement-php-string-xor-with-javascript

Comment: @AlexWindHope ага, уже сделал) порт http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anubis

сейчас думаю, в чего можно упаковать, base64 не подходит.

Comment: @AlexWindHope подходит, работает!